# Get UID firebase auth in variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to get your UID from firebase into a variable? I tried this but the variable is undefined.

```
var userUID;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        userUID = user.uid;
    } else {}
});

console.log(userUID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var userUID;
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser();

if (user)
  userUID = user.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

userUID changes only after Auth object gets initialized, but you log it immediately at script execution.
Try to log it after Auth object gets initialized

```
if (user) {
        userUID = user.uid;
        console.log(userUID);
    } else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onAuthStateChanged` is not a synchronous operation. This is why `console.log(uid)` immediately after will return undefined. You have to wait for the operation to resolve with the current user before you run the logic that needs this `uid`.